# Number of isomers in a 3-sugar oligosaccharide

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers

I recently read that 12288 different oligosaccharides can be formed from the D-isomers of glucose, mannose and galactose. I wanted to try to calculate this, but I keep falling very short of this number.

[image]

Each molecule has the potential to form 6 unique bonds:

[image]

The disaccharide can form 13 unique bonds:

(Note, bonds formed by anomeric carbons shown with an arrow)
[image]

So, if a monosaccharide can form 6 different bonds, this means that:

**6 possible bonds** x **5** **bonds on 2nd sugar** x **2 anomers for seconds sugar** = 60 possible disaccharides

Each of these disaccharides has 13 possible bonds it can make to a third saccharide:

**13 bonds** x **5 bonds of 3rd molecule** x **2 anomers** = 130 combinations for a single dissacharide.

130 combinations per disaccharide x 60 possible disaccharides =7800 isomers.

This is probably a counting error. But maybe I am missing a stereocenter?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the 12,288 figure? I get twice that. Would like to look at work before posting.

Comment: Found it! Google stryer 12288 isomers.

Answer (score 3):

This question is interesting and neglected. Bob made a sensible attempt at solving the problem. I took a different approach. [The number of isomers 12,288 was found in Stryer’s *Biochemistry* (Google: stryer 12288 isomers)]. Of course, *oligo-* means *a few*. I presume this means three in this case. But can D-glucose, D-galactose and D-mannose be used as many times as you want? That would mean 27 (3<sup>3</sup> = 27) permutations which would eventually make the total much greater than 12,288. However, if each hexose is to be used once, then six (6! = 6 factorial) permutations are possible for the location of the hexoses in the oligosaccharide. Division of 12,288 by 6 removes this issue from the question and leaves 2,048 as the number to justify. Now 2048 = 2<sup>11</sup>. The problem reduces to finding 11 stereocenters, *if possible!* 
Let us assume as a point of departure that diagramatic structure **ABC** (top of the illustration; The connectivity C<sub>1</sub>-C<sub>4</sub> is arbitrary.) shows where bonds are formed between the C<sub>1</sub> anomeric carbons and the hydroxyls at C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub>, C<sub>4</sub> and C<sub>6</sub> of another hexose. Another pair of assumptions is that all rings are 6-membered (pyranose) and that all hexoses, as defined, are in the D-series. Finally, assume for the time being that there are no C<sub>1</sub>-O-C<sub>1</sub> connections as typified  in figs. **D** and **E**. 
Rather than define C<sub>1</sub> of hexose **A** as having two stereocenters (α and β anomers), this assignment will be considered in a different way. Hexose **A** is given a value of zero because no attachments may be made at its hydroxyl groups at C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub>, C<sub>4</sub> and C<sub>6</sub>. Hexose **B** has four hydroxyl groups (blue dots) that can form two anomeric, glycosidic bonds at C<sub>1</sub> with hexose **A**. The **AB** connection creates 2<sup>4</sup> (16) stereoisomers. In a similar fashion the hydroxyls at C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub>, C<sub>4</sub> and C<sub>6</sub> of hexose **C** (red dots) form another 16 stereoisomers with C<sub>1</sub> of hexose **B**. The total count thus far is 3! x 2<sup>8</sup> = 6 x 256 = 1536. This result is only one-eightth of the goal of 12,288 or short by a factor of 2<sup>3</sup>. To this point the eight hydroxyl groups considered can only form two configurations each.
Now the anomeric hydroxyl of hexose **C** when bonded to the anomeric carbon of hexose **B** will give not two stereoisomers but rather four (αα, αβ, βα, ββ)(see fig. **E**). Similarly, the same relationship exists between hexoses **B** and **A** (see fig. **D**). These configurations add a factor of 16 (2<sup>4</sup>) to the total. This reasoning leads to a value of (3!) x (2<sup>12</sup>) = 6 x 4096 = 24,576.

If the original analysis considered a structure such as **ABC** having a mutarotating C<sub>1</sub>-OH, then the total might be 12,288. However, **ABC** is a connectivity map, not a chemical structure.

What may be concluded from all of this? The premises set down here may not be those applied by the proposers of 12,288. There may be a flaw in this, or their, analysis. The answer may be 12,288, 24,576 or something else.

[image]